# Chrome: How to identify which tab does a subframe belong to?

Tags: google-chrome, process, cpu-usage

There is some Chrome tab (but I have too many of them opened) that constantly opens a subframe that takes a lot of CPU. I can see that in Chrome's Task Manager - I sort it by CPU, identify it and kill it, but it comes back after a few minutes.

The only useful info that Chrome's Task Manager gives is that it comes from facebook.com, but many websites may have elements pointing to that server (e.g. a comments section in a blog) so I can't use that to identify the tab.

It also gives the PID, that I can look up in Process Explorer. I find it and try to look for the PPID, but that parent process is Chrome's main process which is the parent to all other Chrome tabs.

Is there other way to get more info about this process either with Chrome or with system process information tools (Win10 in this case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that double-click on any row of Chrome's Task Manager makes Chrome switch to that tab, so that's the easiest way.

If a Chrome developer sees this: right-click on Chrome's Task Manager rows should give the option "Switch to this tab"

Answer (score 0):

In chrome sub framing is quite normal. I do not actually understand what you meant here but from what I understand I think quizlet app can help you.

Comment: What is quizlet? Looks like a game/quiz app if I'm not mistaken